# Opensearch dashboard - Add static content

Tags: kibana, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I have some dashboard where it's necessary to add legends more specific.
Is it possible to add a static image or text in a dinamic dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

The work-around is to insert a public url in a markdown visualisation.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/adding-image-to-the-markdown-of-kibana-dashboard/192992